# how to add textfield to firebase under new root?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, textfield

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AxYOY.png)

This method does not work with me , what can i do to add "reminderTextField" to the firebase under a new root?

Comment: Please replace the image of code, with the actual code and use the formatting features of Stack Overflow to make it readable. You'll also want to add a snippet of the JSON you're trying to process to your question (as text, no screenshots). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Answer (score 0):

That code works for me although we don't know what ref is or how reminderTextField is defined. When I run the firebase portion of the code, this is what I get

```
reminders
   Reminder
      Title
         some_auto_id
            date: "the date string"
            message: "some message"
            username: "Shaden"
```

That being said, if reminderTextField is a UI element, you cannot store that. You have to get the text string from the textField and then store that

```
let reminderTextString = reminderTextField.text
```

and then the updated code

```
let parameters1 = ["username": "Shaden", "message": reminderTextString, "date": dateString]
ref.child("Reminder").child("Title").childByAutoId().setValue(parameters1)
```

Comment: Yes, that worked for me before but I don't know what is the problem now, this code didn't work with me :(

Comment: @shadenmsh It's not clear what *didn't work for me* means. That code 100% works - the only thing preventing it from working would be incorrect Firebase rules preventing the write (not being authenticated for example).